# Calculate next row in query based on previous row value

Tags: sql, lag

I have a table and I need to forecast future months, the current structure is with month numbers as the third column

| Multiplier | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1 | 50 |
| 1.4 | 0 |
| 1.8 | 0 |
| 1.7 | 0 |

I use the multiplier against the quantity of the previous month ie 1.4 * 50 and need it to output this in the quantity column in row 2 70 and then cycle through each row repeating the process of using the multiplier on the previous rows quantity.

Is this possible? I can use the lag function to populate row 2 but not any future rows

Comment: As it stands there is no concept of "previous" in your sample data, can you add the table's primary key.

Comment: This is deviating off-topic, but why would you use SQL for this?  This is a trivial problem for a simple program in some modern language.

Comment: @Stu the third column is a date field split out into months

Answer (score 0):

Adding the month, so we have an ordering criterion.

I hope your DBMS supports recursive queries. In my DBMS, Vertica, I would do it like so:

a) create the test table ...

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE
indata(mth,multiplier,quantity) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS (
          SELECT 1,1.1,50
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1.4,0
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1.8,0
UNION ALL SELECT 4,1.7,0
);
```

b) and the query here ...

```
WITH
RECURSIVE with_res AS (
  SELECT
    mth
  , multiplier
  , quantity
  FROM indata WHERE mth=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    chi.mth
  , chi.multiplier
  , par.quantity * chi.multiplier
  FROM with_res par
  JOIN indata chi ON par.mth+1=chi.mth
)
SELECT * FROM with_res ORDER BY 1;
-- out  mth | multiplier |   quantity   
-- out -----+------------+--------------
-- out    1 |        1.1 |  50.00000000
-- out    2 |        1.4 |  70.00000000
-- out    3 |        1.8 | 126.00000000
-- out    4 |        1.7 | 214.20000000
```